# How to trigger HTML5 validity check on an input

Tags: html, forms, validation

Is there a way to trigger HTML5 validation check on an input? Some function or method?

For example, when I click on some image, it checks validity of an input's value but only one. And I don't want any separate validation, just triggering this HTML5 engine validation.

Comment: What should the input contain? Is it required? Could you post some code or a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, it's a throritical question. I want to check to trigger its validity just like i clicked the submit button and things happen.

Comment: So instead of clicking on a submit button you wish to click on a button and that should submit the form, correct?

Comment: No no, when clicking on anything that I specify I don't want the whole form to be submitted. I just want one input to be HTML5 validated (checked) like it happens when you submit a form with html5 rules (required, pattern, etc...)